# Problemas al mostrar imagenes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oracle, iis

tengo este código que imprime imágenes del server, pero solo la puedo ver en el servidor y en internet explorer solamente:

```html
 <img src='file://192.168.10.129/sapshared/FOTOS/KennedyDB/$row[PicturName]' height = '100' width = '100' >
```

el ip que termina en 129 es otro servidor donde están alojadas las imágenes.

El programa está en php corre en IIS y SQL Server.

Comment: Por qué utilizas file? si las imágenes están en otro servidor deberías utilizar el protocolo http, es decir `http://ruta`.

Comment: prueba la respuesta que di en la otra pregunta

Answer (score 1):

El uso de file es generalmente para apuntar a archivos dentro del mismo servidor, en tu caso deberías cambiarlo a HTTP y dejar el source de tu enlace del siguiente modo:

```
<img src='http://192.168.10.129/sapshared/FOTOS/KennedyDB/$row[PicturName]' height='100' width='100' />
```

Comment: las imagenes están en otra pc, que no es un servidor web, solo un file server.